# ACCESS VBA evitar parpadeo al actualizar un form con el Time

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Por código voy leyendo las piezas que se van fabricando y el resultado lo voy colocando en el campo correspondiente de la tabla. Los resultados de esta tabla los muestro en un subformulario continuo y sus txt recogen la información (origen de control) de la tabla que voy actualizando cada 30''. No logro actualizar los valores de los txt si no presiono F5 o utilizo el método requery o recalc, pero si uso estos métodos la pantalla parpadea y la propiedad Painting no evita este parpadeo. He probado con actualizar únicamente los txt afectados y tb escribir directamente en los txt, pero si no le doy a F5 no refresca el subform.

En esta pagina encontré esta función pero cuando llega el programa a “Me.Recalc” la pantalla se refresca y carga.  Necesito evitar eso para que no sea incomodo al usar el formulario

```
Application.Echo False
Me.Recalc
Application.Echo True
```

Comment: He encontrado el origen del problema. El parpadeo viene originado por los labels que tienen condicional. Al usar Requery, Recal o Refresh hace que los condicionales se vuelva a repintar (aunque sean pocos condicionales), el formulario que uso esta usando varios formatos condicionales en las labels. Conocéis alguna forma de evitar que los formatos condicional queden congelados pero que los valores si se pinten.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de realizar la actualización de la tabla en pantalla coloca ésta instrucción

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Después habilítala nuevamente

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Quedaría de ésta manera

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Echo False
Me.Recalc
Application.Echo True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Agus Oz,  la propiedad Application.ScreenUpdating funciona solo para excel. Gracias por tu ayuda pero para Access no es valido

Answer (score 0):

Sé que contesto muy tarde a esta pregunta, pero en Access yo esto lo soluciono:

```
Me.Painting=False
'Resto de tu código
Me.Painting=True
```

Puede que aun así haga un pequeño parpadeo, pero nada que ver que si recalcula muchos registros y se pone como loco a parpadear.